# Store poll responses in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an admin panel which has one of the functions as ADDING A POLL TO THE WEBSITE
But as the number of options provided in the poll may vary, i want its storage to be dynamic.
I.e., I want to ask for number of options while creating new poll.

In my mySQL Table, how should i store the votes, provided that number of options may vary in every poll??

I have heard that there is something like array data type that is used to do it... 
Please help me with an appropriate way to do it.

P.S. I am a newbie to MySQL and using it first time with php.

Answer (score 0):

Learn Database before you try to create application.

[image]